# Boostrap table data from data-url

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am using nodejs and jade with bootstrap plugin Bootstrap table. 
I am having trouble getting it work.

Here is the part of the table in jade

```
h1 Reported Users
   table(data-toggle="table", data-url=reports)
      thead
         tr
           th(data-toggle="matched_uid") Reported User ID
           th(data-toggle="reported_name") Reported User Name
           th(data-toggle="email") Reported User Email
           th(data-toggle="message") Reported Offense(s)
           th(data-toggle="reporter_name") Reported By
```

The table loads like this:

[image]

And when I looked into the browser console, I think the `results` in data-url loads correctly:

[image]

Does my `data-url` valid? Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?
Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

data-url="reports.json"

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="matched_uid">Reported User ID</th>
        <th data-field="reported_name">Reported User Name</th>
        <th data-field="email">Reported User Email</th>
        <th data-field="message">Reported Offense(s)</th>
        <th data-field="reporter_name">Reported By</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

And your json will be

```
[
{
    "matched_uid": "sample",
    "reported_name": "sample",
    "email": "sample",
    "message": "sample",
    "reporter_name":"sample"
},
{
    "matched_uid": "sample",
    "reported_name": "sample",
    "email": "sample",
    "message": "sample"
    "reporter_name":"sample"
},
{MORE},
{MORE},
{LAST}
```

]